# setting up aws credential in flask

Tags: flask, boto

I have been thinking of this, is there anyway to put my credential into 
settings.py.

My generator.py is as following

```
import os
import sys
import collections

import boto
from boto.s3.key import Key
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, abort, request 
from  flask.ext.frozen import Freezer
from werkzeug import cached_property
from werkzeug.contrib.atom import AtomFeed
import markdown
import yaml
from string import strip


...

class Blog(object):
    def __init__(self, app, root_dir='',file_ext=None):
        self.root_dir = root_dir
        self.file_ext = file_ext if file_ext is not None else app.config['POSTS_FILE_EXTENSION']
        self._app =app  #_ for private and internal
        self._cache = SortedDict(key = lambda p: p.date, reverse= True)
        self._initialize_cache()

 ...

app =  Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_envvar('SETTINGS_FILE') #configuration file
blog = Blog(app, root_dir= 'posts')
freezer = Freezer(app)
DOMAIN = 'cuboid.example.net'
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'ABCDEFGHIJK'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'HUIHUGERUGHIUHSIUHH'
```

currently I cant put the credential in it as the boto does not settings.py Can you tell me if there is a way to work **AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID** and **AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY** into settings.py?

Answer (score 2):

Create a file called `settings.py`, place your keys inside of it, load it with `import settings` and then reference them as `settings.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`.

However, from a security perspective you should really use IAM Roles instead. They automatically provide temporary keys to each EC2 instance.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/roles-usingrole-ec2instance.html

Comment: Thanks that's very helpful. I want to know if this will make the code much safer than hard coding it into generator.py?

Comment: Yes. It will. If your application is compromised, the attacker won't have direct access to persistent keys and the damage that can be caused is reduced.